hyperplane intersecting a polyhedral cone
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Consider a family $V$ of non-null vectors in $\R^n$. Consider the (open) polyhedral cone
$$C(V) = \{x\in\R^n\;:\;v\cdot x> 0\,,\;\forall v\in V\}\,.$$
We will call $C(V)$ the cone generated by the family $V$. Note that this might be a slightly unusual definition, in the sense that $C(V)$ in general does not correspond to the polyhedral cone of the vectors $\alpha  v$, where $\alpha>0$ and $v$ is in the convex hull of $V$.
Now consider a family of non-null vectors $V_N=\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Assume that $C(V_N)$ is non-empty.
The problem I am considering is the following.
We are given a vector $v_{N+1}\neq0$. Denote $V_{N+1}$ the family $V_N\cup\{v_{N+1}\}$.
What conditions on $v_{N+1}$ ensure that the polyhedral cone $C(V_{N+1})$ is non-empty and differs from $C(V_N)$?
Current progress. For $v\in\R^n$ non-null, denote the hyper-plane orthogonal to $v$ as $$H(v) = \{x\in\R^n\;:\;x\cdot v=0\}\,.$$ If $H(v_{N+1})\cap C(V_N)$ is non-empty, then it is clear that $H(v_{N+1})$ will cut $C(V_N)$ in a non-trivial way, and ensure that $C(V_{N+1})$ is non-empty and differs from $C(V_N)$. On the other hand, if $H(v_{N+1})\cap C(V_N)=\varnothing$, then $C(V_{N+1})$ is either empty or equal to $C(V_N)$. So, here is an equivalent question.
Let $w\in\R^n$ non-null.
What is the set of vectors $w$ such that $H(w)\cap C(V_N)$ is non-empty?
It's clear that this is exactly the set of $w$ that are orthogonal to at least one element of $C(V_N)$.
I am interested in characterising this set in terms of the family $V_N$.
So far, I've worked out how things work in dimension $2$. If $N=1$ everything is trivial and one just need to ask that $w$ is not proportional to $v_1$. For $N\geq2$, there the polyhedral cone is just defined by two vectors (all others are redundant), say $v_1$ and $v_2$. Then, I guess $w$ must be proportional to a vector which is a convex combination of $v_1$ and $-v_2$. So, there must exist $\alpha\in\R$ and $\beta\in[0,1]$ such that $$w = \alpha(\beta (v_1+v_2) - v_2)$$ if I am not wrong. This comes essentially from geometric considerations, drawing things down. However, already in dimension 3 things get messier and my drawing skills are definitely not good enough. I wonder if there is a smart way to approach the problem. Any help is welcome.
I think it's easier to characterise $w$ in terms of the convex generators of the cone, namely a family $U=\{u_j\}$ such that any element of a polyhedral cone $C$ is proportional to a convex combination of the vectors in $U$. In this case, I think one needs to ask that $w$ is normal to at least one point in the interior of the convex hull of the $U$. But I wonder if there is a simple way to express it in terms of the vectors in $V$, defining the half planes.

You always have $0 \in H_w$, so it is not clear what you are asking.

Unless I have a bad nD vision, the case of vector-hyperplanes (i.e. hyperplanes as you define them with $x\cdot w=0$) looks to me reduced to a point whereas the case of affine hyperplanes $x\cdot w=c \ne 0$ is more interesting, giving a polytope.

@copper.hat True, I mean a non-trivial intersection... I'll edit it, thanks for pointing it out

@JeanMarie I don't understand what you mean

I should have added : for $v_k$s assumed in general position. Besides, why don't you restrict your study to the case $n \le m$ : in such a case, instead of "general position", I would say "independent"...

I think the answer is that $v_{n+1}$ should not lie in the convex cone generated by $v_1,..,v_n$.
